# How to use Url in ajax to call a handler.ashx

Tags: javascript, asp.net, ajax, jquery

Hey, the directory of my project is like :

```
project 
  codes
    fileupload(ashx)
  scripts
  image
  web-pages
    home(aspx)
    about(aspx)
    FileUpload(aspx)
```

Im using in my FileUpload(aspx) this ajax function :

```
<script>

function ajaxFileUpload() {
    $.ajaxFileUpload({
        url: "/FileUpload.ashx", // The problem is here
        secureuri: false,
        fileElementId: 'fileToUpload',
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function (data, status) {
            if (typeof (data.error) != 'undefined') {
                if (data.error != '') {
                    alert(data.error);
                } else {
                    ShowUploadedFiles(data.upfile, filename);
                    $('#fileToUpload').val("");
                }
            }
        },
        error: function (data, status, e) {
            alert(e);
        }
    });
}
</script>
```

How to call my handler(fileupload.ashx) from this function :
I tried many ways :

```
1 - url: "../codes/FileUpload.ashx", Not working 
2 - url: "~/codes/FileUpload.ashx", Not working
3 - url: "./codes/FileUpload.ashx", Not working 
4 - url: "/codes/FileUpload.ashx", Not working
5 - url: "/project/codes/FileUpload.ashx", not working 
6 - url: "codes/FileUpload.ashx", not working 
7 - url: "/FileUpload.ashx", not working
```

PS : when I change the directory of my FileUpload.aspx and place it in the main folder of project ... it will work perfectly with this url : codes/FileUpload.ashx

So any ideas ?

Comment: This `/project/codes/FileUpload.ashx` must working, if you run it from IIS server. Now you need to open the browser tools and see if he find or not the file. If not, then its path the issue.

Comment: Question: does `FileUpload.ashx` get served, if you hit it directly from a browser?

Comment: @McGarnagle : Yep i tried it many time and it works fine .. but when i put fileupload.aspx in web-pages folder it dont work .. !

Answer (score 0):

If you're hosting in IIS and the root of your web app is set to the /project/web-pages/ directory you're going to need to have all of the other dirs for the web app within that directory. IE:

If the working URL structure is such that http://your.url/home.aspx is working then your project will need to be structured like:

```
/project/web-pages/
/project/web-pages/image
/project/web-pages/scripts
/project/web-pages/codes
```

otherwise the files at /project/codes are not going to be served by IIS. Unless you set up a separate IIS virtual directory for /codes.

If IIS is configured such that your URLs look like http://your.url/web-pages/home.aspx then the /codes directory *should* be accessible using the /codes/fileupload.ashx relative path assuming that you have IIS configured for the root of the website to be the /project/ directory.